# Two shortcuts for a QAbstractButton

Tags: qt, qabstractbutton

I need to assign two shortcuts to a QAbstractButton, but I cannot find a way to do that.

It seems the only method is QAbstractButton::setShortcut(const QKeySequence & key).

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QAbstractButton only accept one shortcut sequence. Try to give to shortcut in QtDesigner like Alt+A & Alt+Z and you will see that you have to do Alt+A **AND** Alt+Z to execute shortcut. So you can not achieve to have 2 shortcuts as you want.

But there is a solution:

All `QObject` have a function named [`event`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qobject.html#event) that receives all events. You can create your own class that inherits from your class button (`QPushButton`, etc. or directly from `QAbstractButton` if you want to have a personalized button) with a list of `QShortcutSequence` (or a pair if you only want 2 shortcuts) and re-implement the `event` function to track the [`QShortcutEvent`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qshortcutevent.html). Don't forget to release all other events to be process by parents classes.

Comment: I ended doing what you suggested : create my own class inheriting QPushButton.